# Matching commas between HTML tags in a CSV

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I've got a CSV which I'm trying to reformat which contains some HTML, but the HTML has commas in it, which is making life difficult.

How can I use regex to replace the commas within the HTML tags with HTML Entities.

Thus far I've tried things like `>(.+?),(.+?)<` to no avail.

I'll probably use a text editor to do the actual substitution, most probably Atom.

EDIT:
Here's a sample:

```
U,4,EXAMPLESKU,<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">  <p align="center"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3"><strong><span style="font-size: medium;">&nbsp;<span style="font-size: medium;">Example</span></span></strong></font></p>  <p align="center"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">Content goes in here, including commas, sometimes multiple.</font><a href="mailto:email@example.com"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">email@example.com</font></a><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">. <br/>  Some more content here, including commas, sometimes multiple.</font>&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>  </font>,image.jpg,9.99,Example,3~53,0.00,0,0,0,0.500,2,1
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: @npinti I've added a sample row from the CSV

Answer (score 0):

See my post that solves this problem for more detail.

`^(?:(?:"((?:""|[^"])+)"|([^,]*))(?:$|,))+$` Will match the whole line, then you can use match.Groups[1 ].Captures to get your data out (without the quotes). Also, I let "My name is ""in quotes""" be a valid string.

Comment: Could you link to your post please?

Comment: This won't work on the full CSV as this groups content between commas, however I can't tell how many commas there will be in a given column.